# Changing the Date format from one class to another

Tags: java

I am using this class right now.

http://www.cse.yorku.ca/common/type/api/type/lib/CreditCard.html

I have a credit card, I used the method of `getExpiryDate()` for my credit card. 
And it gives me the date in a form of: `Mon April 06 09:23:10 EDT`
I'm looking to have the date in this form:

`06/04/2015` and the time is not needed.

```
    PrintStream out = System.out;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    GlobalCredit credit1 = new GlobalCredit().getRandom();

    out.print("Enter report range in years ... ");
    int range = in.nextInt();
    out.println("Cards expiring before " + range + " year(s) from now: ");



    for (CreditCard cc : credit1)
    {

        out.println(cc.getNumber() + "\t");
        out.print(cc.getExpiryDate());

    }
```

thats part of my code, (didnt copy beginning). I got to do something in the for statement. I got to relate cc.getExpiryDate() to Date Class somehow

Comment: Take a look at this class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Does `cc.getExpiryDate()` return a `Date` or a `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

for (CreditCard cc : credit1)
    {

        out.println(cc.getNumber() + "\t");
        out.print(sf.format(cc.getExpiryDate()));

    }
```

Comment: @ Roddy of the Frozen Peas no it returns a java.lang.Date, See http://www.cse.yorku.ca/common/type/api/type/lib/CreditCard.html

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String startTime = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be looking at java [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).